# Arranging angle measurements in ascending order

Tags: angle

**Arrange the following assortment of angle measures in ascending order; 210°, 350°, 2π, 5.3 radians, 90°, 1.7 radians, π/3 , 1 radian, 55°, π.**

I only just started learning about angle measurements and so I'm struggling with this question. How would I correctly place them in ascending order? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about the constant of proportionality between degrees and radians?

Comment: I was taught that 2π radians = 360°, π radians = 180°, and 1 radian = 57.295.. = 60°.

Comment: If you know that there are $2\pi$ radians for $360^{\circ}$, then how many radians in $1^\circ$?  How do you compare measures that are in different units?

Comment: To point you in a similar direction, which is longer, $2$ inches, or $5$ centimetres?  $0.97$ miles, or $1450$ metres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four angles are in degrees: 210,350,90,55. Three are in radians: 5.3,1.7,1. Another three are also in radians but expressed in terms of $\pi$.

So you need to convert them all to some common unit, say radians. Thus multiply each of the degree values by $\pi/180$ and use $\pi=3.1416$ to convert the multiples of $\pi$. Then you should be able to see the correct order.

Comment: Would the answer be 2π, 350°, 5.3 radians, 210°, π, 1.7 radians, 90°,π/3 , 1 radian, 55° ?

Comment: @Savannah Yes! Well done.